# Index/optimization for aggregation that returns distinct field values from inside of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an aggregation that returns distinct field values from inside of an array.

Is it possible to create an index that will make the execution faster?
Or maybe it's possible to optimize this query?

Query:

```
aggregate(
  [
    { "$match" : { "status" : { "$ne" : "ARCHIVED"}}}, 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$dataRecords.dataSets.name"}}, 
    { "$unwind" : "$_id"}, 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id"}}, 
    { "$sort" : { "_id" : 1}},
    { "$skip" : 0},
    { "$limit" : 20}
  ]
)
```

My (simplified) document is defined as:

```
{
  "_id" : JUUID("7183471b-616e-48df-879d-17980e6e27e2"),
  "dataRecords" : {
    "modelId" : "ABC",
    "dataSets" : [
      {
        "_id" : "XYZ13",
        "name" : "XYZ",
        "variables": "Lots of customized data"
      },
      {
        "_id" : "TUV4",
        "name" : "TUV",
        "variables": "Lots of other customized data"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status" : "PUBLISHED"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to simplify the expression of this request, but it may not be possible to meaningfully improve the performance given the current schema.

##### Alternative Syntax

For reference, I have copied your starting sample into a playground which is available [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nxx5E102GB-). The output is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "TUV"
  },
  {
    "_id": "XYZ"
  }
]
```

With the current aggregation pipeline, the first `$group` does not seem to be necessary. If we eliminate it and adjust the field names accordingly, a slightly simpler rewrite of the pipeline is:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "status": {
        "$ne": "ARCHIVED"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$dataRecords.dataSets"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$dataRecords.dataSets.name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 20
  }
]
```

This version produces the same result ([demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2sEXMN301aj)). It does eliminate an entire blocking stage (the first `$group`), but that change alone won't result in it being significantly faster as there are still two other blocking stages.

It appears that you may be looking to do some sort of pagination here (based on the final three stages in the pipeline). If that isn't a strict requirement, or if some of that logic could be performed elsewhere, then the `.distinct()` syntax would be a more straightforward and readable way to express the intent:

```
db.collection.distinct(
  'dataRecords.dataSets.name', 
  { "status": { "$ne": "ARCHIVED" } }
)
```

This changes the format of the results, but the contents are effectively the same:

```
[ 'TUV', 'XYZ' ]
```

##### Performance

As one of the fields is an array, there does not seem to be a way to efficiently retrieve this information from MongoDB today.

If, and only if, the majority of documents in the collection **are** already archived (e.g. have a `status` of `ARCHIVED`), then an index on that field (`{status: 1}`) will help narrow the result set and reduce the overall amount of work that must be done. Regardless, the database currently has to do all of the following for every candidate document:

- Unwind the array
- Group *all* of those values together, this must complete entirely before moving on to the next stage
- Manually sort all of that data, this must complete entirely before moving on to the next stage
- Skip the requested number of computed results

Hypothetically, it should be possible to traverse an appropriate index in a manner that reduces the number of keys scanned. While that approach would require jumping around in the index, it could potentially be much less work overall depending on the cardinality of the values. MongoDB will already do this (automatically) when neither field is an array, but doesn't seem to do it in this case where the source value (`dataRecords.dataSets.name`) is an array.

If you did need to meaningfully improve the performance of this read operation, then you may need to consider alternative approaches. Perhaps periodically materializing the result or otherwise changing/enhancing the schema to capture this list of distinct values elsewhere.